# Swedish text Localization on iphone

Tags: iphone, localization

I want to know about localization.The exact requirement is copy/paste text should be changed to swedish text accordingly  while entering the text in UITextField.Can any one have source code or example link for this?

I meant the copy/paste tip text appears when editing the UITextfied.How to change this to swdish text?

Comment: That's a setting on the phone itself, try it with a phone set to swedish.

Comment: 1 upvote in 40 questions. not good...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can have dynamic text in localization, i guess you should call google translator so it translates the copied text, you'll get a json response for that.

Take a look here for example:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1448/how-to-translate-text-with-google-translate-and-json-on-the-iphone